Preserving features of a mesh when flattening using uvs with geometry nodes
ive read a few articles about how to flatten using uvs in geometry nodes. And i was wondering what is the correct math to preserve the features of a mesh as close as possible.
Basicly, what i am doing is flattening a cylinder that has a bit of sculpted details on it. And i want to flatten it so that is nice and rectangular. But i would like it to presererve most if details if possible. What i have looks almost ok, up to the point where it seems like some of the mesh is going in and out itself. Just wondering if there is extra math i need to do. Or if this is as good as its going to get.
Thank you!



here is the blend file to go alone with this question


Do you work exclusively with a cylinder (strait axis, constant radius except where sculpted) ? Because in this case, a coordinate transformation might be more straightforward. Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Yeah, my idea is to just be able to flatten whatever cylinder-esque shape i give it, such as a tree trunk or a cable.
Here is the blend file

